# Adjoints and orthogonal projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The proof of problem 10A.2 of Axler's measure theory text seemed fairly straightforward to me. But I found something which appears to be a counterexample, but I know must be untrue (I'm misunderstanding some property of the adjoint or inner product).

[image]

I can see that $T^* = P_U$, the orthogonal projection of U. This follows because $v - T^*v$ is orthogonal to $u$ for each $v \in V$ and $u \in U$.

But also, for any $v \in V$ and $u \in U$,

$$
\langle u, v \rangle = \langle Tu, v \rangle = \langle u, T^* v \rangle
$$

Because $0 \in U$, we have
$$\langle 0, v \rangle = \langle 0, T^*v \rangle  $$

which implies that $v = T^*v$. But then $v = P_U(v)$ even when $v \notin U$, which is impossible.

Where is my error?

Comment: The adjoint of $T:U\to V$ is defined as the function $T^*:V\to U$ satisfying the equation $\langle Tu,v\rangle=\langle u,T^*v\rangle$ for all $u\in U$ and all $v \in V$. You've observed that the identity operator on $V$ satisfies the equation required of $T^*$. But that identity operator is not a function $V\to U$ (unless $U=V$), and so it doesn't qualify to be the adjoint $$T^*$.

Comment: I don't believe I'm assuming that $T^*$ is the identity operator. My first line of equalities simply uses the definition of adjoint and definition of $T$. Can you point to which equality/line I've made an error?

Comment: The error concerning the identity is "which implies that $v=T^*v $ near the end of your question. (The previous line, about $0$, seems irrelevant but not erroneous.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because $0\in U$...

That's not how these arguments work. When you have that $\langle u,y\rangle=0$ for all $u$ and you conclude that $y$ is zero, you need to have that $y\in u$ and the way to conclude if that you then get $\|y\|^2=0$. But, in general, from $$\langle u,v-T^*v\rangle=0$$ for all $u\in U$, what you prove is that $v-T^*v\in U^\perp$. Nothing else.

Comment: As a subspace, we have $0 \in U$. So we have $ \langle 0, v - T^*v \rangle = 0$. This implies that $v - T^*v = 0$. Are any of these statements incorrect?

Comment: Yes, of course it's incorrent. $\langle 0,x\rangle=0$ no matter what $x$ is. It tells you nothing whatsoever about $x$. What you say is the same as saying that if $z$ is a number and $0\times z=0$ you can conclude that $z=0$.

Comment: Ah yes of course -- I misread a proposition in my book, and didn't take a moment to realize my error. So glad I made this post though, I knew I was committing some very basic error!